# How do I integrate $\int\frac1{ \sqrt{x^n + 1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int\frac1{ \sqrt{x^n + 1}}dx$$

This question popped up in my mind after we took trigonometric substitution in calc II. I tried solving it until I got $${\sinh}^{{\frac{2}{{n}}-{1}}}{\left(\theta\right)}$$ and then it got ugly afterwards.

I came up with some reduction formula, but then the values did not really work out when I tested them out with constants and limits.

Moreover, a quick search on the internet showed me that such type of questions are solved with complex analysis, Mobius transformation etc.

I think this integral is solvable for all infinite integras and finite rationals, but again I am not sure.

Comment: The solution to this integral involves a hypergeometric function.

Comment: $n = 2$ (inverse) trigonometric; $n=3$ or $4$, elliptic integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The antiderivative for general $n \neq 0$ is expressible in terms of a [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) or, just as well, the incomplete beta function:
$$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^n + 1}} = x \cdot{}_2 F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{n}; 1 + \frac{1}{n}; -x^n\right) + C}} .$$
For most values of $n$ this expression cannot be written as a closed expression in elementary functions, but for certain special rational values it can. We can read off from the result of your hyperbolic trigonometric solution that there is a closed form for $n = \frac{1}{m}$ and $n = \frac{2}{m}$, $m \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

If $n$ is nonzero and rational, say, $n = \frac{a}{b}$ for $a, b \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}$. Then, the substitution
$$x = u^b, \qquad dx = b u^{b - 1} \,du$$ transforms the integral to
$$b \int \frac{u^{b - 1} \,du}{\sqrt{u^a + 1}} .$$

- For $a = 1$ (so that $n = \frac{1}{b}$), the substitution $u = v^2 - 1$, $du = 2 v \,dv$, transforms the integral to the polynomial integral $$2 b \int (v^2 - 1)^{b - 1} \,dv .$$
- For $a = 2$, (so that $n = \frac{2}{b}$), the substitution $u = \sinh t$ transforms the integral to the hyperbolic integral
  $$b \int \sinh^{b - 1} t \,dt .$$
- For $a = 3, 4$ (so that $n = \frac{3}{b}$ or $n = \frac{4}{b}$), the integral is
  $$b \int \frac{u^{b - 1} \,du}{\sqrt{u^3 + 1}} \qquad \textrm{or} \qquad b \int \frac{u^{b - 1} \,du}{\sqrt{u^4 + 1}} ,$$ which can be expressed in terms of elliptic functions. For example, $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4 + 1}} = e^{-\pi i / 4} F(e^{\pi i / 4} u, i) + C ,$$ where $F$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Of course, if $n = 0$, the integrand is constant.

Comment: You could write this as an [incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html). Also for $n=\frac k6,k\in\Bbb Z$, it is an elliptic integral.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you, I'll the former comment to my answer. How do you see the statement that if $k \in \frac{1}{6} \Bbb Z$ then the answer can be expressed in elliptic functions?

Comment: Click the decimal approximation [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-+beta%28e%2F%284+%281%2F3%29%5E3%29%2C1%2F6%2C1%2F2%29%2F%283+2%5E%282%2F3%29+e%5E%281%2F6%29%29%2C+inverseweierstrass%28%281%2F3%29%2C%7B0%2Ce%7D%29) or input other values. It gives a form in terms of $_2 F_1(\frac12,\frac 16;\frac 16+1,z)$, the incomplete beta function, and [inverse Weierstrass P](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/InverseWeierstrassP/), expressible through $F(x,k)$.